# Imported library package does not exist in Java project

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I created an Android project and imported a library using its source code. I added it as an existing module.

When my project referenced a library class, the IDE offered me to import the package. It did it without problem. I compiled the library and it was okay.

I used this import:

```
import eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage;
```

When I compiled again, the source code shows no errors, yet I get these errors:

> java: package eu.janmuller.android does not exist java: package
>   eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage does not exist

So the IDE offered me the package as it knows it. On second thoughts, it does not.

What should I set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the imported module once so when I restarted the IDE, it was marked with a number (CropImage1) but it compiles now. If I rename it again, it won't compile.

**NEVER** rename anything when dealing with modules!